# Why do I seem as not authenticated in Symfony debug profiler?

Tags: symfony, authentication, profiler

When I open my *home page* by `http://domain/app_dev.php/ru/` in Symfony debug profiler I have the following info:

```
Logged in as:  admin
Authenticated: No
Token class:   UsernamePasswordToken
```

My `security.yml` is:

```
providers:
    users:
        entity:
            class: BWUserBundle:User    
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    auth:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /%locale%/user/sign-in
            check_path: user_sign_in_check
            success_handler: bw_user.auth_success_handler
        logout:
            path:   user_sign_out
            target: home

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Why am I not authenticated after successful login as **admin**? Help to understand what it means?

Comment: We need to see your `security.yml` to debug the problem, and would also like to know what is your working url you are experiencing this behavior?

Comment: Victor, does your User class implement UserInterface?

Comment: @tomazahlin No, I implemented `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface`

Comment: Where and how is your user provider set up in your security.yml. form_login should have a provider node.

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I added provider to question

Comment: But shouldn't it also appear under the `form_login` section as well?

Comment: I remember having the same problem, try opening the profiler and check what roles your user has. I had the same problem when my roles array was empty, after I fixed it, it was all good.

Comment: @tomazahlin My role is `ROLE_ADMIN`. And I has access to the control panel by `http://domain/app_dev.php/admin` as well

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I think it is not necessarily by [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: in your home controller can you get user? `$this->getUser()`?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás There is nothing happens. But I try to check is granted with `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')` and it authenticated me. Why?

Comment: I meant some debugging along this line: `$user = $this->getUser(); var_dump( $user->getName() );` But if you get `true` to the following code: `var_dump( $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') );` then you should have no problem: you are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually removed the Symfony's default firewall:

```
dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```

You must declare it to be first firewall in your `securty.yml`.

Comment: I removed it, but still not authenticated

Comment: No, you need to have it in you `security.xml` :) Based on you question, I assumed that you have previously removed it...

Comment: I understand, Symfony's default firewall is present, I forgot to show it in question

Comment: Ah, ok then... I will think of something else ;)